# What does "HAD" imply here? (I didn't realize you HAD + noun)

Tags: past-tense, backshifting

When you say "I didn't realize you had the apple", does it mean the person who is spoken to still has "the apple"? Or because it's "HAD", does it imply the person doesn't have the apple anymore?

Answer (score -1):

Like most statements using a past tense, there is no implication about the present.

> My wife was interested in economics

says nothing about the present. She may still be interested in economics, or she may not. The statement deals with the past rather than the present.

> I loved her when we married, but have hated her since we divorced

makes sense.

> I loved her when we married and love her more after a life shared together

also makes sense.

The past may or may not differ from the present.

Comment: OK...I will take a slightly different approach to my previous Q. So, IF this person, who is spoken to, presently has the apple, can I  say "I didn't realize you *had* the apple"? Or should I say, "I didn't realize you *have* the apple? Or can I say both?

Comment: In my opinion it is perfectly natural to say "I didn't realise you had the apple" knowing that the person still has it. The past tense _had_ relates to _didn't realise_, even if the speaker has only just seen the apple in the person's possession.

Comment: Hi, @KateBunting! So you mean it's more of a matter of matching tense, right? I'd love to know if using *had* would be more natural than using *have* then. (Thanks so much! Wish I could know how to upvote your answers in the comment section.)

Answer (score -1):

If you unexpectedly meet someone you know, at a party for example, "I didn't know you were here" is much more idiomatic than "are here". It's difficult to give a logical explanation, but it comes naturally to a native speaker.

Comment: "Yesterday I found the apple in my purse and ate it." Would the answer be a. "I didn't realize you had the apple." or b. "I didn't realize you had had the apple."?

Comment: @JannPoppinga I think either would be possible.

Comment: This is not easily understandable, if one doesn't realize it is about the tense. Maybe you should include that, or stick to the example given?